# What is the most recommended Twitter library to use for .net for a web application?

Tags: c#-4.0, twitter

I found a list at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet but I don't know which is the last technology/api twitter is focusing on.
As I am new to twitter api I don't know where to start from, also, so I thought that somebody could recommend where to start from and with what.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/). I'm using it in one my project and I find it very useful.

It even has a streaming (stream and user stream; use these if you need real time updates in your application and want to avoid hitting the hourly limit of the REST API) API implementation and comes with a nice documentation and some examples.

Before jumping into coding the API I strongly suggest to read at least the basics of OAuth and of course the overview of Twitter APIs to know which one is what you really need (https://dev.twitter.com/start).

Comment: Hi Norbip, I have tried today Twitterizer. The point is that I haven't found an example which goes all process: authorize users and post a message. I am still looking for that...

Comment: For the authorization use the included ASP.NET sample application (in theExampleApplications folder). After you go through the auth process you will have the required tokens (access token and access token secrets) for an API operation like post a message. In your case this would be TwitterStatus.Update(). Its first parameter is the token set (consumer and access keys) the second is the text of the new tweet.

Comment: Should I save token key and token secret for a user in database so i should make a connection between a user logged and tokens? Don't you have a working project, or live example?

Comment: btw: after directed to callback.aspx should I forword to another view in order to publish a message?

Comment: I don't have a live one at the moment, sorry. And yes, you should store these tokens for your users in order to send API requests in the future. Otherwise the same OAuth process should be repeated always, which isn't user friendly. On your next question: After you have the tokens (and you have them after the auth process) just make the appropriate API call from your code. You don't need any redirection for that.

Comment: Norbip, I am sorry for beeing so ... I still have some doubts; The same request I have to do with Twitter as i have already done with Facebook. Let me exaplain how I have done it: when you enter on page where you can publish a message will appear a button(from fb) it's included like this:         <p>
            <fb:profile-pic uid="loggedinuser" facebook-logo="true" linked="false">
            </fb:profile-pic>
            <fb:login-button autologoutlink='true' perms='read_stream,publish_stream'  >
            </fb:login-button>
        </p> and when press recieves token from fb, to be contin

Comment: and as I have that token I don't have to store anywhere, for will expire. The question is how should i deal with callback.aspx for when I press to publish a message goes throug page_load() and will through 401 error, I am confused; that is why I requested for a small project ... there is nowhere over the entire web :D

Comment: AFAIK FB uses OAuth 2.0. In Twitter's case the version of OAuth is 1.0a so don't expect the same behaviour. BTW the example says: "If you click on an example link and are given a 401 exception, come back here and double check your consumer token value." If it returns to callback (and it does if you provide the valid keys) you can make the API calls with the tokens on the callback site. :) If this - pretty long - conversation answered your questions please mark my post as an answer later.

Comment: Hi again Norbip ;) i really appreciate your effort, still I have some questions:

Comment: suppose a user goes on my page: DefaultTwitter.aspx. Do I have to ask my user to go always to (eg) https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=Y6YOijcUSyJuWKvI6g3diFQfetUIjvskTfHHJxgr? If not and case when I sould base on info taken when authorized how do I identify that with current twitter user? And how to i put a button to deny connection bettwenn twitter and my application. Hope you understand.